# Split string with multiple delimiters into columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing, delimiter

I have data in my SQL Server table in string format that looks like this:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyons.png)

**Sample data**

```
create table Test (
 resource_type varchar(300)
);
insert into Test (resource_type) values
('account_id:535533456241,resource_type:buckets,resource_name:tni-prod-diva-backups'), 
('account_id:460085747812,resource_type:buckets,resource_name:bda-sit-tims'), 
('account_id:123456789012,resource_type:buckets,resource_name:fi.fa.foo.bar.baz');
```

I want a SQL query to get an output like this:

| account_id | resource_type | resource_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 535533456241 | buckets | tni-prod-diva-backups |
| 460085747812 | buckets | bda-sit-tims |
| 123456789012 | buckets | fi.fa.foo.bar.baz |

I am working with this code, but its not giving me the expected output. Could someone help?

```
SELECT 
    REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE([resource_type]), ',', '.'), 1)) AS [Street],
    REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE([resource_type]), ',', '.'), 2)) AS [Street],
    REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE([resource_type]), ',', '.'), 3)) AS [Street]
FROM
    [Test].[CloudHealth]
```

Output of this query:

[image]

Comment: Please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, we cannot make use of an image of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I was not sure how to upload consumable text in the question. As the data I am working with comes from a JSON file which has gone through many hoops to come to me...merely looking for advice

Answer (score 0):

If that string is transformed back to a JSON format, then it's possible to process it like a json.

```
SELECT 
  JSON_VALUE(json, '$.account_id')    AS [account_id]
, JSON_VALUE(json, '$.resource_type') AS [resource_type]
, JSON_VALUE(json, '$.resource_name') AS [resource_name]
FROM Test t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES('{"'+REPLACE(REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(t.resource_type,'json'),':','":"'),',','","') +'"}')) ca(json)
```

> | account_id | resource_type | resource_name |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 535533456241 | buckets | tni-prod-diva-backups |
> | 460085747812 | buckets | bda-sit-tims |
> | 123456789012 | buckets | fi.fa.foo.bar.baz |

Tests on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=84dd1e20d8f0f62f7d771b166decdc86)*